# Surgical burnination of visual tag

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

Over 200 questions are tagged [visual](/questions/tagged/visual)+[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) separately (see [visual+c#](/questions/tagged/visual%2bc%23)). Do the mods have special, laser precision burnination abilities that can surgically remove [visual](/questions/tagged/visual) from those?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any legitimate purpose for the [visual](/questions/tagged/visual) tag's existence, and having looked through the questions tagged with it, I don't see any where it's justified. Seems to me that the best thing to do would be to burninate it completely.

I'll gladly change my opinion if someone can show a legitimate use of the tag.

Comment: It's strikingly rare, but there are some legitimate uses (see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017254/visual-c-editor-for-kids)). Even then, how useful is that versus all the confusion inherent with the tag?

Comment: Removing [tag:visual] would also prevent erroneous tagging of visual studio and visual basic as separate tags. I'd be relived of some self-imposed cleanup duty...

Comment: So, in essence, I agree with you, @TheGuyWhoDisagreesWithYou